# Сравнение перебираемых элементов массива

Tags: php, mysql

Существует таблица с сотрудниками. По каждому сотруднику есть несколько строк.

Таблица выводится в цикле while. Как мне сделать так, чтобы происходило сравнение предыдущего значения элемента массива с последующим. В случае пока значения совпадают (`Иванов == Иванов`), то делать определенные арифметические операции. Если не совпадают (`Иванов == Дмитриев`), то выводить переменную с результатом, и заново начинать те же действия только уже для значения (`Дмитриев`). Ну и т.д.

Попытался сделать так:

```
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itog");
$mas = mysql_fetch_assoc($db);
$fio = $mas['fio'];
while($mas = mysql_fetch_assoc($db)){
    if($fio == $mas['fio']){
        $fio = $mas['fio'];
        //Всякие вычисления результат которых попадет в переменную $result  
    }
    else {
        $result = 0;
        $fio = $mas['fio'];
        //Всякие вычисления результат которых попадет в переменную $result 
    }
}
```

Но это не совсем правильно, потому что когда фамилии не совпадут, сработает `else`, а при последующей итерации цикла фамилии будут уже равны, и соответственно, сработает первая часть условия(`then`), и результат уже будет неверным.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверять совпадение по ФИО - плохо, надо по id.
2. Это надо делать не в цикле, а в sql-запросе (group by и соответствующие аггрегирующие функции).
3. Не надо делать fetch до цикла, а в начальное значение лучше присвоить какой-нибудь null, чтобы после первого вытаскивания сработала вторая ветвь.
4. Не забыть обработать строку в else-ветке. Или убрать if с `==`, а соответствующие действия делать это после проверки на `!=` (то, что сейчас в else-ветке), но без всяких else.
5. Не забыть вывести результат после цикла.

Вместо 4-5 можно сделать вечный цикл с вытаскиванием и break в середине.

---

> Если Вас не затруднит, не могли бы Вы видоизменить мой алгоритм, и показать наглядно пожалуйста.

Алгоритм я изменить могу приблизительно (т. к. php не знаю), но дальше сам разберёшься, наверное. В любом случае, так делать нехорошо, правильно было бы переместить всю эту логику внутрь sql-запроса.

Просто для информации привожу алгоритм с минимальным дублированием кода:

```
// Я предполагаю, что одному id гарантированно соответствуют одинаковые fio
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itog ORDER BY fio, id");

while (true) {
    if (!($mas = mysql_fetch_assoc($db)) || $id !== $mas['id']) {
        ВыводЧегоТо();

        if (!$mas) {
            break;
        }

        $id = $mas['id'];
        $result = 0;
        ДругиеОбнуления();
    }

    ВсякиеВычисленияРезультатКоторыхПопадетВПеременнуюResult();
}
```

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит, не могли бы Вы видоизменить мой алгоритм, и показать наглядно пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

- Во-первых, основной косяк здесь в том, что первая строка вообще исключается из всех вычислений. Значение $fio перед циклом надо приравнять к пустой строке.
- Во-вторых, нет смысла запоминать старое значение, если оно и так равно новому. А вот если НЕ равно - то запомнить надо обязательно. Хотя скорее всего это просто опечатка, `$mas = $mas['fio'];`
- В-третьих, вывод должен быть отсортирован по полю `fio`. Иначе этот код будет считать все что угодно, но только не то что нужно.

А в-четвертых, и в самых главных - **все "арифметические операции" должны производиться в базе данных**, и запрос должен возвращать уже готовый результат

Comment: Во первых: если я приравниваю переменную к пустой строке, то соответственно условие не сработает, потому что пустая строка будет не равна первому значению из элемента массива. Получается нужно по другому поставить условие.

Answer (score 0):

Не буду повторяться по поводу проведения вычислений непосредственно sql-запросом, а не в php. Если другого выхода у Вас нет, можно попробовать так:

```
$ar_users_fio = array();        // Массив фамилий
$ar_users_info = array();       // Массив данных
$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itog");
while($mas = mysql_fetch_assoc($db)){
    // Ищем фамилию
    $key = array_search($mas['fio'], $ar_users_fio);
    // Если она не найдена, то записываем её в массив фамилий и потом в массив данных для такого же ключа заносим вычисления.
    if( !$key ){
        $key = $mas['itog_id'];     // или любой другой вариант уникального ключа
        $ar_users_fio[$key] = $mas['fio'];
        $ar_users_info[$key] = 'Всякие вычисления по этому пользователю';
    }
    // Если фамилия уже была, то добавляем к имеющимся данным новые вычисления
    else{
        $ar_users_info[$key] += 'Дополнительные вычисления по этому пользователю';
    }
}

// Результат:
foreach( $ar_users_fio as $key => $fio ){
    echo $fio.' - '.$ar_users_info[$key].'<br />';
}
```

Можно конечно сразу все сделать с помощью одного массива, где ключ = фамилии, а значение = вычислениям, но лучше этого не делать и расщедриться на два массива. :)

Comment: Предполагаю, что приведенный запрос всё же выдуман для примера, поэтому промолчу про то, что сортировку (как минимум) в такой запрос добавлять очень желательно. :)